# PM2 and babel always "Port is in use"

Tags: node.js, babeljs, pm2

I has been using PM2 to run and monit node process for awhile and it works fine until I try to use babel.

I'm not sure what is the real problem, but when I starting a project with babel, it can't stop showing `Port 3000 is already in use`.

This project is a copy of another one. They are almost the same except the `scripts` in `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run babel | node ./bin/www",
    "babel": "./node_modules/.bin/babel server -d lib"
}
```

and the original is much simpler

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  }
```

I use start the process by `run process.json`, and add `"exec_interpreter": "babel-node"` in the project with babel.

I also installed some new packages to the copy project including babel, babel-core, babel-loader, react, react-dom, react-hot-loader, webpack and webpack-dev-server. And I changed the code from ES5 to ES6 like that's why I use babel.(yes, I'm trying to use react and transfer to ES6 based on a normal express project)

When I reboot my mac and run the original project without babel, everything is fine. Then I stop the process and go on to start the project with babel, it keep throwing `Port 3000 is already in use`.

```
COMMAND    PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google     394 brick   14u  IPv6 0x432e592f22d3b26b      0t0  TCP localhost:52261->localhost:hbci (CLOSE_WAIT)
Google     394 brick   16u  IPv6 0x432e592f22d397ab      0t0  TCP localhost:52262->localhost:hbci (CLOSE_WAIT)
Google     394 brick  213u  IPv6 0x432e592f246f87ab      0t0  TCP localhost:52264->localhost:hbci (CLOSE_WAIT)
node      1210 brick   13u  IPv6 0x432e592f22d377ab      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
```

I use `lsof -i:3000` in shell, it shows there's a node process and 2-3 named Google processes(I'm using chrome) is using the port. Even I killed the process, it reappears(with different pid).

I have no idea what's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this in GitHub. It is indeed the come case babel thing. One of the workarounds is to use babel's [require hook](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/) in the entry file.

Can read more discussion here: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1643